# Using prometheus-community helm chart how can I expose custom pod labels

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, kube-state-metrics

I've deployd default chart (`helm install test prometheus-community/prometheus`) to my minikube (Kubernetes version 1.21.5).

I would like to have custom pod labels attached to `kube_pod_status_ready` metric which  comes from `kube-state-metric`.

E.g.: I have pod running with custom label `my-app=foo`. I would like to see this label on my `kube_pod_status_ready` metric.

I've try to update prometheus chart config with following settings but this didn't helped

```yaml
...
kubeStateMetrics:
  ## If false, kube-state-metrics sub-chart will not be installed
  ##
  enabled: true

# kube-state-metrics sub-chart configurable values
# Please see https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-state-metrics
#
kube-state-metrics:
  metricLabelsAllowlist:
    - pods=[*]
...
```

How can I achieve it? What do I need to change in Prometheus configuration chart config to add my custom pod labels?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this out? I got my problem solved using this.

```
kube-state-metrics:
  extraArgs:
    - --metric-labels-allowlist=deployments=[*],services=[*] # - --metric-labels-allowlist=[*] for allowing all labels (not recommended). Also you can use fixed labels too
# if relabelling required
  prometheus:
    monitor:
      metricRelabelings:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: (.*)bazaar_(.*)
          replacement: ${2}
        - action: labeldrop
          regex: label_(.*)
```

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/13/kube-state-metrics-v-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the above configuration was ok. I just need to use `kube_pod_labels` metric in conjunction with `kube_pod_status_ready`:

```
kube_pod_status_ready{condition="true"} * on (namespace, pod) group_left(label_app) kube_pod_labels{label_app="my-app-name"}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Where did you add the above line? Is there a way to add it to values.yaml for helm?